# How to Check for Empty data entry before populating ListBox

Tags: c#

```
private void LoadExcelSheet(string path, int sheet){
    _Application excel = new Excel.Application();
    Workbook wb;
    Worksheet ws;
    string data = "";
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
    ws = wb.Worksheets[sheet];
    listBox1.Items.Clear();

    for (row = 1; row < 10; row++){ 
        data = " ";
        for (col = 1; col < 3; col++) {
            data += ws.Cells[row, col].Value2 + " "; 
        }

       //wanted to filter out empty cells/data and at the same time count
       //number of items in the list... row should stop.. I think!

       if(data == null){
          break;
       }

    listBox1.Items.Add(data);  
}
```

The `if` statement doesn't seems to work no matter what I do. I would appreciate it very if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: You set data = " " so it will never be null.  Check for length == 1 instead.

Comment: `data` is never null - you are initializing it to an empty string.

Comment: not only is `data` never going to be null, as Jason mentions, but you are appending a space character to it for every cell you check.  So unless you check zero cells, `data` will never be an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

use it like this:

```
 if (data.Trim().Length < 1)
  {
      return;
  }
```

use `return` not `break`

Comment: Thank$ Reds... the results was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: If this resolved your problem then mark as answered.

Comment: Forgive me, but how do you do this?

Comment: the down arrow of this answer you can see the check button.. you can click it to make it as answered.. you can also click the up arrow to upvotes the answer.

Comment: @BOB.G see the following for information on how to accept an answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition like this

```
If(string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
{
  Break;
}
```